# While dragging an item from my app, can I limit dragging only into Windows explorer and get the target path when done?

Tags: c#, windows, events, uwp, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing a drag and drop capability, that should allow users to drag files from my UWP C# app to an external target.

The problem is that the file is not necessarily available when dragging starts, and needs to be fetched/processed so it's ready for the drag operation.

When the file is not available yet, dragging should only be allowed to Windows explorer with the possibility of getting the target path where the file was dropped to.

The app will likely have the *broadfileSystemAccess* restricted capability, so a possible solution to allow dragging of unavailable items will be to drag a dummy item, and replace it with the actual file, once it's fetched.

The only relevant events I found for the draggable element flow are: [dragStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragstarting?view=winrt-19041) and [dropCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dropcompleted?view=winrt-19041), and it seems that none of them provide the relevant API.

Is there any more API which I might have missed, or any other ideas about how this might be possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you can not limit only dragging into the Windows explorer, there is no such api or method to set the target app. However, when you drop the item to other places, it will show a flyout ,you could click cancel button from it to cancel operation.